# Android v7 GridLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-widget

I keep getting this error when I put my v7 GridLayout into a Linear Layout:

Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

If I don't have the GridLayout within a Linear or Relative layout then it will work fine, but I have to have the GridLayout in some kind of Layout so then scrolling can work but I keep getting the error above?

Does someone know to prevent this from happening within a Layout?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a know issue with Lint: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52831.

Just add the tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" to the Gridlayout item:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
...
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">
```

To be able to use this namespace, make sure you included it in your root tag:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```